# Spring Data MongoDB: Unable to resolve a bean for 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations'

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, javabeans, spring-data

So I've set up Spring Data MongoDB with a Java Configuration and everything has worked fine so far. Now I wanted to use "Repositories" and created a "UserRepository". As soon as I created the corresponding Interface (extending CrudRepository) I encountered the following exception while deploying to jBoss:

> Unable to resolve a bean for 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations' 
>   with qualifiers [@javax.enterprise.inject.Any(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Default()]

Therefore I added the following method to my SpringMongoConfig:

```
@Bean
public MongoOperations mongoOperations() throws Exception {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongo(), dbName);
}
```

But it did not help and the exception persists.

I am fairly new to Spring and therefore I quickly ran out of ideas. Can anyone help?

**I fixed it...**

...by adding the annotation *@Produces* to the method *mongoOperations()*:

```
@Bean
@Produces
public MongoOperations mongoOperations() throws Exception {
    return new MongoTemplate(mongo(), dbName);
}
```

Not sure why this is necessary / why the problem occurred at all.